# .Net 4.0 app slower on 64 bit than 32 bit (Profiling and possible solutions) (app is using NetAdvantage)

Tags: .net, performance, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, infragistics

We have got .NET app written in VB .NET 4.0 / VS2010, compiled with all projects set to the AnyCPU setting for both Debug and Release configuration. We have noticed that when this app is run on a 64 bit environment (tested on Windows Server 2003 R2 and 2008 R2) that the app then takes at least double as long (in absolute terms about 25 secs) as opposed to around 6-12 seconds on a 32 bit environment (Win XP and 7) to start up.

I should add that the 64 bit systems are powerful servers, definitely more powerful than the other tested 32 bit systems. All other apps were faster on 64 bit, but not our poor app ;) (And we did test the apps at different times, under different load, and the results are always pretty much the same.)

As said above, the app is built using AnyCPU and it does run as 64 bit assembly under 64 bit OS (checked via TaskManager). The app itself is a WinForms app, making use of NetAdvantage Forms v10.3 and is regularly querying and writing to MS SQL Server 2008.

The different target machines are all on the same network, so the path to the database (same database was used for the performance tests) for example is the same, I don't think the problem is around the database or the network itself.

One thing I did notice, which seemed odd to me, was that when I built in different "profiling steps" using a stopwatch during the startup of our MainForm that the InitializeComponent method took twice as long on 64 bit, around 4 seconds opposed to 1.5 on 32 bit.

It's the very same app we deploy on both systems, no different config.

So I have got two questions:

Any idea what the cause of this could be?

And: What's the best way of determining the "offending" pieces of code? Currently I use stopwatches and try to narrow it down. But it looks to me like everything is slower on the 64 bit machines as far as our app is concerned, so I am not too sure I can break it down to specific statements.

Thanks all for your help, very much appreciated...

Comment: If your development environment is 64 bit, try running the `Profiler` using the `Performance Wizard` in Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't read the entire question, but check if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2947118/389966

Comment: I noticed exactly the same thing and posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161080/net2-assemblies-hosted-in-net4-app-perform-better-in-x86-than-in-anycpu-mode

Comment: @Moon. No it's a 32 bit dev environment. But I might get access to a 64 bit dev env. Thanks for the tip. Edit: Oh, but we only have VS Professional - that wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: Don't assume anything.  Measure.

Comment: Red Gate and JetBrains offer trials of great profiling applications. Its a futile game to try and guess where some random application is bogged down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out, that as soon as we switched from compiling from AnyCPU to specifically x86, i.e. also run as x86 on a x64 bit platform, we were back to our "good speed".

Comment: It is good you got back to the fast speed by compiling directly to 32-bit which runs as a 32-bit process, but did you ever find the answer as to why your app took longer to start up? How much RAM did your x64 servers have?

Comment: One thing that occured to me is that we make heavy usage of NetAdvantages WinForms. I am inclined to think that they use code that performs faster on 32bit environments, but I haven't verified this. Any more experience on this is very welcome. And re the question of RAM: We have loads of RAM on all machines, all the same speed as well and loads of spare RAM during execution as well, so it must be somewhere else.

Comment: Remember this, The `platform target` doesn't change the compiled IL-code, it's only a limitation for the `JIT-compiler`. The limitation is mostly usefull when using native api's (compiled for a specific platform target)

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue - and yes, the JIT is to blame.  By judiciously using msgbox, narrowed it down to a *method* that would take 10 seconds to start (by calling message box just before calling the large method, and then as the first line of the large function.)  And, yes, only saw this when compiling as AnyCPU, but not when explicitly x86; and not when running in debug.

In my case, it was a 5000 line Windows Forms `InitializeComponent`.

To prove this, run (elevated) "`c:\windows\<.net framework dir>\ngen.exe install <myassembly.exe>`" which will compile a native image.  If this fixes it, then yes, the JIT was to blame.

Long term fixes, either:

- use ngen each time you deploy the program to rebuild the native image (or ngen update to rebuild, but obviously only works once installed once);  (Downside is managing the ngen image(s) and the time it takes to ngen.  This is the route I took, because there's an overall performance boost for larger applications.)
- or you can add the attribute `<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)>` to the method.  (Disables JIT on the method, so it's slower to execute *but* you don't pay the initial overhead of JITing, which is the the expensive part for us)

(I suspect that doing both is fruitless as that would mean giving up the native image of the large method for no gain.)

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same performance issue with an application. And yes, compiling it as x86 solved the problem; it then ran fast on either platform. But the real reason for the slow launch response time is due to 32 to 64 bit migration issues. I think that when the app launches and it goes through the JIT process to turn code into IL, the compiler is determining that issues exist within the code (like un-type safe code) that it has to resolve before it can run in 64 bit mode. I ran across this article and am now trying to go through the app to determine which pieces are causing the issues. See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx.
I could leave it alone since it works but ideally, it would run better in 64-bit mode if the issues were resolved.

Comment: Interesting! Please post more, when you've looked more into it.