# VB.NET: Do I need to reference 64 bit SMO dlls

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, dll, smo

My machine is running 64 bit windows with Visual Studio 2015 + SQL Server 2014 express.

I need to create the client application with SMO that should run on both 32 bit and 64 bit machines. I just read the [Microsoft MSDN document about how to reference SMO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162129%28v=sql.120%29.aspx). So I know that I need to reference these dll files:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll, 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll, 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll, 
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll
```

But I am confused a bit as these files are present in 2 folders:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\

If any one can suggest me what approach should I use.

1. Configure my project for separate builds for 32 and 64 bit and reference the corresponding SMO dlls using the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145803/targeting-both-32bit-and-64bit-with-visual-studio-in-same-solution-project). (This will lead to 2 different exe files for 32bit and 64bit, so I need to create different installer for both platforms! correct me if I am wrong)
2. Keep one build configuration i.e. AnyCPU is my project and reference the dlls from C:\Program Files (x86)\ only. (Will it work?)

I know this can lead to open discussion, but I am more interested if anyone can confirm whether solution 2 works for me. And why should I prefer solution 1 over solution 2.

Comment: This question is quite old. I am adding my final finding to conclude this question from my side. I ended up with using only x86 configuration for application, and it can run on both 32 and 64 bit Windows. I decided this as 64 bit applications are slower (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979774/net-4-0-app-slower-on-64-bit-than-32-bit-profiling-and-possible-solutions-ap). So I only need 32 bit dlls and only one exe/installer.